# Jetpack API for Wordpress Network

Tags: multisite, plugin-jetpack, json

Wordpress provided a lovely Json API with Jetpack.

I cannot seem to to find a way, or documentation on getting data from a multisite wordpress install?

It seems to fail on sites like www.example.com/site1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I  answered my own question.

The slash in the URL messes up the API call. However urlencoding the URL will get around it.

IE:

`$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$site = urlencode("subdomain.example.com/site1");
$response = file_get_contents(
  'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/' . $site .'/',
  false,
  $context
);`